# Разбить число на список цифр

Tags: python

От пользователя, с помощью функции `input`, я получаю шестизначное число.

После этого нужно разбить его на 6 самостоятельных чисел, например, в список.

Как этого можно добиться?

Например, число `123456`, надо разбить на `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> list(str(123456))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Comment: `str(int)` это квадратичная операция в Питоне, поэтому [она может долгое  время занимать для больших чисел (`gmpy2` имеет более эффективный алгоритм)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279).  Ещё `O(k**2)` алгоритм: `f = lambda n, digits=[]: f(n//10, [n%10] + digits) if n else digits or [0]` (just for fun).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = list(map(int, input()))
print (a)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]