# Альтернативные способы разбиения числа на список цифр

Tags: python

После прочтения [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153958/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) вопроса (Найти сумму и произведение цифр числа), у меня возник интерес к допустимым вариантам разбиения числа на список из цифр.
Итак, есть число, которое мы разбиваем на список из отдельных цифр.

```
num = 123
```

Если мы делаем

```
y = list(map(int, str(num)))
```

То получаем массив чисел [1, 2, 3]
Если же мы просто вызваем

```
y = list(str(num))
```

То получаем ['1', '2', '3'], что естественно идёт как массив символов.
Так вот, существуют ли альтернативные функции преобразованию строки в массив чисел, но без map? Имею ввиду вшитые в пайтон или какую-нибудь библиотеку.

Сам я смог найти лишь такой вариант (вот [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262786/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80)):

```
f = lambda n, digits=[]: f(n//10, [n%10] + digits) if n else digits or [0]
```

Но это явно не то, что я ищу.
В общем я буду очень благодарен люому, кто мне подскажет альтернативы.

Comment: Красивый вариант с лямбда функцией)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56953659/6944845

Comment: А что вы хотите найти? Придумать то вариантов можно много разных

Comment: @CrazyElf, хотел бы найти я что-то уровня x = abrakadbara(num), и на выходе x =[1,2,3]. Т.е. не самостоятельную написанную функцию, а вшитую в одну из известных библиотек. Так-то варианты с циклом как у MaxU и strawdog рабочие, но это именно что созданная пользователем функция, а я надеялся что есть что-то простое и уже готовое. Если правильно помню, то в Racket есть как раз такая стандартная функция. И её часто предлагают реализовать самому через map.

Comment: @MaxU, откровенно говоря, предложенный вами вариант мне нравится больше - он короче и проще для чтения.

Comment: товарищ!
Отметьте какой-то ответ как "принятый".
Людям это приятно. ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, ну так-то пока ни один из данных ответов не подходит под то, что я ищу. Если до понедельника ничего нового не появится - то отмечу ответ AivanF.

Comment: О как интересно.
А что именно вы ищете.
Или иначе - чего не хватает имеющимся ответам?
Я сам эту задачу по разному решал  и вроде бы все варианты приведены ))

Спрашиваю - чтобы написать "тот"  вариант )

Comment: Я ищу функцию, входящую в состав какой-либо библиотеки (изначально надеялся, что есть что-то подобное и в числе стандартных). Т.е. вида x = required_function(num) и на выходе получаю список. Так-то, если самому делать руками, то я как  MaxU и Strawdog делал бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть одна интересная библиотека, которая работает много быстрее, чем лобовое str(int).
Правда на очень больших числах. Это библиотека ***[gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/)*** - по сути обертка над сишной библиотекой быстрых вычислений  [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).
Если str(int) работает как O(n2), то их родная функция работает быстрее. Жаль исходного кода нет.
Итак:

```
  text = 1000*"0123456789"
  %timeit str(int(text))
3.28 ms ± 27.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

  %timeit mpz(text).digits()
1.9 ms ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Ну это на случай, когда надо именно "стандартная функция из библиотеки".
Конечно, можно и так:

```
  %timeit str(mpz(text))
1.91 ms ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Ох, Василий, огромное спасибо! Это именно то что я искал! Находил обратную функцию в этой библиотеке, но видимо поисковый запрос составил неправильно и вот эту найти не смог. Спасибо вам ещё раз!

Answer (score 3):

## списковое включение

```
res = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
```

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Классический вариант без работы со строками чисто по остатку от деления:

```py
def split(number):
    result = []
    while number > 0:
        result.append(number % 10)
        number //= 10
    return result
```

#### 2. А также моя однострочная реализация – ведь цикл `while` вполне можно заменить на `for`, т.к число итераций известно наперёд:

```py
import math
split = lambda num: [num//10**i%10 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log10(num)))]
```

#### 3. Ещё можно в функциональной парадигме определив `opposite reduce`:

```py
def reduce_opposite(fun, num):
    while num > 0:
        it, num = fun(num)
        yield it

split = lambda num: list(reduce_opposite(lambda x: (x%10, x//10), num))
```

<sub>Спасибо опыту LISP'a `:D`</sub>

#### Результат везде один:

```py
>>> print(split(31415))
... [5, 1, 4, 1, 3]
```

При желании, все варианты можно можно дополнить `reversed` для более натурального порядка цифр в списке.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = "123"
b = [int(x) for x in a]
print(b)
```

> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re
num = 124509333
digits = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d', str(num))]
```

Ну раз речь о вариантах то еще один:

```py
a = 4567
l = []
while a >= 1:
    a, b = divmod(a, 10)
    l.insert(0, b)
print(l)
```